# Extract the pixel value with only the polygon with the largest coverage inside that pixel?

Tags: r, raster

We can create a shape file and polygon like this

```
 library(terra)
 f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
 v <- vect(f)
 set.seed(0)
 r <- rast(nrows=2, ncols=2)
 values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE) + 10
 plot(r)
 plot(v,add=T)
```

As you can see, all polygons are located inside one pixel. How to extract the pixel value with only the polygon with the largest coverage inside that pixel?

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question. The value would be the same for all polygons that fall in a single grid cell; so would you just ask for the cell number (`extract(cell=T)`. What do you want for polygons that cover multiple cells? With this example

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(xmin=5.5, xmax=7, ymin=49, ymax=50.5, nrow=2, ncol=2)
values(r) <- 1:4
plot(r); lines(v)
text(v)
```

You could do

```
e <- extract(r, v, exact=T)
head(e)
#  ID lyr.1    fraction
#1  1     1 0.069797760
#2  2     1 0.044516667
#3  2     2 0.004358702
#4  3     1 0.047880106
#5  3     3 0.009956781
#6  4     1 0.017031392
```

And you can see how much of a cell is covered by a polygon. Perhaps that helps.

Comment: yes exactly: "The value would be the same for all polygons that fall in a single grid cell"  . so one of these polygons will have the largest fraction in this pixel. I am looking to return this largest polygon, its ID, and the value of the pixel.

Comment: I have a feature in the shape file called "name", how to return this instead (or as another column) of the ID column in e?